# Postgres CROSSTAB double pivoting

Tags: postgresql

A query I pivot in Postgres with crosstab looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CROSSTAB(
            $$
              select email, period, action, 
              count(*) over (partition by action, period, email) as times  
              from flightlog
            $$,
            $$
                VALUES ('login'),('view'),('download')
            $$
        ) 
        AS (email text, period text, login int, view int, download int)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

which produces the output like:

```
email                period    login view download
john.doe@mysite.com  2017_04    44   32   2
john.doe@mysite.com  2017_06    23   12   2
jane.doe@mysite.com  2017_04    14    6   0
jane.doe@mysite.com  2017_07    22   10   5
joe.doe@mysite.com   2017_01    55   32   0
```

which I want to double pivot to look like this:

```
email 2017_01_login 2017_01_view 2017_01_download 2017_02_login 2017_02_view ...
joe.doe@mysite.com 55 32 0 0 0
etc
```

how would a query look like I wonder? how should it better be approached?

Comment: I concatenated email with period to produce the right set, now need to split the string and do second pivoting